# How to create index for model in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, indexing

Here's my model class：

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_status = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    sub_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    Options.index_together = [
    ["email"],
    ["auth_code"]
    ]

    def __unicode__(self):
    return "email=[%s], auth_status=[%s], sub_datetime=[%s]." % self.email, self.auth_status, self.sub_datetime
```

What I intend to do is to create index for `email` field and `auth_code` field respectively. But when I issue command: `manage.py sqlall main`, the output contains no `create index` part, which is as follows:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `main_subscribe` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `auth_code` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `auth_status` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `sub_datetime` datetime NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

I don't really know how to use `Options.index_together` properly. So could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks a lot.

**P.S.**

I just have knew that `db_index=True` will just do the job, but still, I want to know how to realize it by `Options.index_together`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to define a Meta inner class to use meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#meta-options). Also note that [`index_together` is defined slightly differently](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#index-together) to your original code:

Eg:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_status = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    sub_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ["email", "auth_code"],
        ]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "email=[%s], auth_status=[%s], sub_datetime=[%s]." % self.email, self.auth_status, self.sub_datetime
```

Answer (score 2):

Meta options should go in `class Meta:` inside your model like so:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auth_status = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    sub_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ["email", "auth_code"]
        ]
    ...
```